# WHERE Clause with conditions in it

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I want to create a where clause that will take into account the termination date and say if they hire date is between these values and the term date isn't on or before the hiredate - IE the employee never started - how would I go about that?  So far I have this:

```
SELECT A.AdpID                                                   AS EmployeeID,
       ISNULL(A.Lname, '')                                       AS [Last Name],
       ISNULL(A.Fname, '')                                       AS [First Name],
       ISNULL(A.PrimaryEmail, '')                                AS [Email],
       ISNULL(M.Fname + ' ' + M.Lname, '')                       AS Manager,
       ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), A.HireDate, 101), '')        AS HireDate,
       ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR(100), A.TerminationDate, 101), '') AS TermDate,
       ISNULL(DIV.DivisionName, '')                              AS Division,
       ISNULL(FUN.FunctionName, '')                              AS [Function],
       ISNULL(DEP.DepartmentName, '')                            AS Department,
       ISNULL(WGP.WorkgroupName, '')                             AS Workgroup,
       ISNULL(LOB.CcaLOBName, '')                                AS LOB,
       ISNULL(MAES.EmpStatusDesc, '')                            AS [Employee Type]
FROM   dbo.Associates AS A
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.Associates AS M -- Look up for associate information
                    ON A.SuperPrincipal = M.AssocId
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.MasterCCALob AS LOB -- Look up line of business
                    ON A.LobID = LOB.CcaLOBID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.MasterAssocEmpStatus AS MAES -- Look up for employee type
                    ON A.EmpStatusID = MAES.EmpStatusID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.AssociatesDepartment AS DEP WITH(NOLOCK) -- Look up for Department
                    ON A.AssociatesDepartmentID = DEP.AssociatesDepartmentID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.AssociatesDivision AS DIV WITH(NOLOCK) -- Look up for Division
                    ON A.AssociatesDivisionID = DIV.AssociatesDivisionID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.AssociatesWorkGroup AS WGP WITH(NOLOCK) -- Look up for WorkGroup
                    ON A.AssociatesWorkgroupID = WGP.AssociatesWorkgroupID
       LEFT OUTER JOIN dbo.AssociatesFunction AS FUN WITH(NOLOCK) -- Look up for Function
                    ON A.AssociatesFunctionID = FUN.AssociatesFunctionID
WHERE  ( LEN(A.TerminationDate) = 0
         AND ISNULL(A.HireDate, '1900-01-01') BETWEEN '2015-10-01' AND GETDATE() )
        OR ( LEN(A.TerminationDate) > 0
             AND ISNULL(A.TerminationDate, '1900-01-01') > ISNULL(A.HireDate, '1900-01-01')
             AND ISNULL(A.HireDate, '1900-01-01') BETWEEN '2015-10-01' AND GETDATE() )
ORDER  BY A.HireDate DESC
```

There where clause is as bad as can be because I get the craziest results back from this

Comment: Please post schema, sample data, expected results and actual results, ideally as a SQLFiddle.

Comment: `LEN(A.TerminationDate) = 0` - is `TerminationDate` a string?

Comment: termination date is a smalldatetime

Comment: So use `A.TerminationDate IS NULL` instead.

Comment: Thanks @D Stanley that is what I was missing.  Much appreciated.